# Why cannot instances of classes be used as values?

Tags: haskell

Why cannot I write something like:

```
data Color = R | G | B deriving Show

showColor :: Show Color
showColor = Show Color

main = do
    putStrLn (showColor.show R)
    putStrLn (showColor.show G)
```

Why are instances of classes not first class citizens in Haskell?

Comment: Why do you want it? You can just say `putStrLn (show R)`.

Comment: @n.m. `show` will take the instance of the class in the current scope. In my example I can pass a different instance of Show Color with non-default implementation.

Comment: Multiple instances is a bad idea: https://wiki.haskell.org/Multiple_instances

Comment: @Nicolas Looks like a bad design of the language. In Scala I can write as many instances of a typeclass as I want and import only that instance that I need.

Comment: No. In the worst case it can be seen as a tradeoff. We use newtypes to differentiate different typeclasses instances.

Comment: Haskell is not designed with multiple applicable instances in mind. Instances are here to be implicit, which can only happen if there's only one of them applicable. If you want to pass functions explicitly, just do that. Allowing instances to be both implicit and explicit depending on whatever would complicate the language design, with little real benefit. It's a trade-off between simplicity and usefulness.

Comment: @n.m. I still don't understand why the question is downvoted. Most of people come to Haskell from OOP languages and expect that instances of classes can be passed as values. So, I don't think my question is totally stupid.

Comment: I have no idea why it's downvoted. I don't think it's stupid. I have actually upvoted it. For people that are coming from OOP: Haskell classes are not types and have no associated values. They are not the same as OO classes (some sources claim they are "just like" OO classes but this is misleading).

Comment: By the way, in Idris language (which is a more or less direct descendant of Haskell) multiple named instances are allowed, with special syntax to choose the needed „overloading“ in method calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to discuss *why* a certain feature of the language is as it is, since only the designers of the language can really answer that. What however happened is that they decided that each type can have at most one instance for each class. This is likely to be driven by the fact that instances are meant to be used implicitly. Consider a class

```
class Foo a where foo :: a -> String
```

and this module

```
import A  -- defines an instance Foo Int
bar :: Int -> String
bar n = "The number is " ++ foo n
```

The `bar` function *implicitly* refers to module `A`'s instance. Now suppose we add another import

```
import A  -- defines an instance Foo Int
import B  -- defines another instance Foo Int
bar :: Int -> String
bar n = "The number is " ++ foo n
```

This is now ambiguous. Haskell might have provided a syntax to disambiguate this, but instead chose to disallow it. One advantage is that whoever reads the code can more easily find the used instances, since there can be only one.

Multiple instances can be partially simulated, though. A GHC extension allows one to define implicit parameters, allowing one to specify a different "instance" for those parameters at each function call:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}

data Color = R | G | B

showColor :: (?showC :: Color -> String)  => Color -> String
showColor c = "The color is: " ++ ?showC c

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let ?showC = \c -> case c of R -> "Red" ; _ -> "Not Red"
     in putStrLn (showColor B)
   let ?showC = \c -> case c of G -> "Green" ; _ -> "Not Green"
     in putStrLn (showColor B)
```

The output of the above is:

```
The color is: Not Red
The color is: Not Green
```

The Agda programming language does not have type classes, but has [implicit instances](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.InstanceArguments) which play a similar role. There, an instance is implicitly passed (as in Haskell) but if desired you can manually override the implicit argument and use a special syntax to specify a different instance.

Comment: The biggest reason to allow only one instance is "coherence". If I build a `Map` or a `HashMap` or whatever, and I choose a different `Ord` or `Hashable` instance for different operations, it will not be long before I start getting wrong answers and/or weird errors.

Comment: @dfeuer Agreed. Yet one can specify an `Ord` instance which violates transitivity and still break `Map` invariants. Ditto for a functor instance which does not satisfy its laws. Having the ability of overriding the default instance would also remove the need for the `...By` functions. I have mixed feelings about this design choice: it does bring a coherence advantage, but we do lose some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, type classes are pretty implicit. (For example, you cannot explicitly export or not export a class instance — which is occasionally annoying.)

The whole *point* of a type class is that it's a bunch of functions where the correct one gets selected automatically. If you want to be able to pass in a different function each type — well, just *do that!*

For example, there's a class

```
class Monoid m where
  mempty :: m
  mappend :: m -> m -> m
```

So we could do something like

```
fold :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
fold (  []) = mempty
fold (x:xs) = x `mappend` fold xs
```

And yet, nobody does that. Instead, they explicitly pass in the parameters:

```
foldr :: (x -> y -> y) -> y -> [x] -> y
foldr f y0 (  []) = y0
foldr f y0 (x:xs) = f x (foldr f y0 xs)
```

Because that way, it's much easier to fold the same data-type with multiple different functions / start values.

If you want to be able to "show" a value multiple different ways, just pass the show function in as an argument. If you want the function to automatically pick the right show function for the data-type, use the `Show` class — but in that case, there can be only *one* instance (because that's kind of the point).

Comment: Ummm... not many people use `fold`, probably, but `foldMap` is reasonably popular.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind type classes is in the name: a type class is a class (or set) of types (which all support a given interface).

For example `Eq` is the class of types that support equality.

A function with type `Eq a => [a] -> Maybe a` is specifying that the type variable `a` ranges over the types that are members of `Eq`; this you need proof that your type is a member of `Eq` before you can call this function.

An instance then is just a constructive proof that a particular type is a member of a class, by demonstrating how the type supports the interface.

Seen this way, it's not just that Haskell doesn't support multiple instances; the idea of multiple instances doesn't make sense. A type is in a class or it isn't; the notion of class/set allows you to enquire about membership, but not to store multiple different implementations.

Most critically, a function shouldn't be able to provide different return values for the same input, just because you used different membership proofs! And existing Haskell code *does* rely on this property: the classic example being the functions in `Data.Map` which (almost) all have an `Ord` constraint in order to operate on a `Map` as a tree internally. If it were possible (and normal) to have many different instances of `Ord` for a type and pass one of your choosing at each call, then this would be a wildly unsafe interface!

The practice of defining laws for a class that valid instances must conform to will also depend on this property. If I write a set of interrelated functioned that assume all instances of `Monad` uphold the monad laws, it's quite likely that my code is broken if different instances can be provided to different calls operating on the same data.

Note that Scala does *not* have type classes. What it has is implicit parameters; there is a *design pattern* to implement type classes yourself using implicit parameters. But it's a leaky abstraction; you can use implicit parameters to do things that do not fit the conceptual framework of a "set of types".

Haskell implements type classes basically using implicit parameter passing, but it *enforces* the abstraction; instead of requiring all uses of implicit parameters that are for type classes to be selected coherently, Haskell rejects any situation where instances *could* be incoherent. The implicit parameters are an internal implementation detail; asking why they are not first class is a bit like asking why vtables are not first class in an OO language.

These days Haskell does explicitly support implicit parameter passing (with an extension), so you could probably use the same design pattern to implement "multiple instances" in code that you write. But code written with that facility is expecting the implicit parameters to be *parameters*, and should work when different values are passed arbitrarily. Code written using type classes expects that the type class abstraction is what's being used.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is hard to understand mainly because

```
showColour :: Show Color
showColour = Show Color
```

Doesn't really make sense. How can `Show Color` be of type `Show Color`?
`Show` can be seen as a constraint, so ultimatly `Show Color` is a `Bool` and in our case will evaluate to True.

Anyway, static scoping can be achieved using module. You can easily do something like

```
module Color where

import qualified Prelude

data Color = ...

show :: Color -> String
show c = Prelude.show c
```

And then use `print (Color.show R)`.

Comment: If you rewrite this code to Java, you will find that it makes sense: `Show<Color> showColor = new ShowColor<Color>()`

Comment: Maybe, but that's an Haskell question not a Java one. Moreover, even in Java, the type `Show<Color>` is different from the value `ShowColor<color>`.

Comment: Constraints are *not* like `Bool`! Their logic is constructive, not Boolean!